# React Native Login with Mysql database using fetch. getting : Network request failed error

Tags: mysql, react-native, user-registration

so i'm trying to follow this tutorial for Registration : https://reactnativecode.com/react-native-user-registration-example-tutorial/#comment-878

i’m using WampServer on Windows 10. I did as mentioned.

I created a folder called “/react” under “C:\wamp64\www\react” and put the two .php files there .
when i put “localhost/react” in my browser i can see the .php files .

i changed the URL to : ‘http://localhost/react/user_registration.php’

But i’m still getting that error .. i’m not sure what i’m doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens simply because react-native consider localhost as an URL but it doesn't have a domain :

**Solution**

**On Windows =>**

Run [Ctrl] + R

Then type : "cmd", press enter

write "ipconfig" then press enter

a list of IP configurations will show, copy the IP address besides **"IPv4 Address"**, it's under **"Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:"**, it starts with **192.168.xxx.x**

**on MAC =>**

http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/21/find-ip-address-mac/

You will now need to replace the URL with this IP Address

you will have this at the end :  **‘http://192.168.xxx.x/react/user_registration.php’**

as you've seen, i have replaced localhost to the ip address taken from  the CMD [i.e IPV4 Address]

You can also use only free hosting website like Awardspace, 000Webhost to test your app on a real device. Use your local server or this ip address, you can't fetch the data from real device

Hope this will help you!
Franz